# How do I query all the rows from a table?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a calendar that has to mark-up taken dates. For example I have 3 records in the table but only the last the most recent record added keeps displaying. How do I make all the rows show? Here is how the problem looks:

http://prntscr.com/jq25ax

And this is the query that I use to display the dates. So how do I make it show all the taken dates? Do I have to make the query in a for loop that goes until `num_row`?

```
<?php

function getCalendar($year = '', $month = '')
{
    $dateYear = ($year != '') ? $year : date("Y");
    $dateMonth = ($month != '') ? $month : date("m");
    $date = $dateYear . '-' . $dateMonth . '-01';
    $currentMonthFirstDay = date("N", strtotime($date));
    $totalDaysOfMonth = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $dateMonth, $dateYear);
    $totalDaysOfMonthDisplay = ($currentMonthFirstDay == 7) ? ($totalDaysOfMonth) : ($totalDaysOfMonth + $currentMonthFirstDay);
    $boxDisplay = ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay <= 35) ? 35 : 42;
?>
        <div id="calender_section">
            <h2>
                <a id="prev" href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('prev')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
                <select name="month_dropdown" class="month_dropdown dropdown"><?php
    echo $this->getAllMonths($dateMonth); ?></select>
                <select name="year_dropdown" class="year_dropdown dropdown"><?php
    echo $this->getYearList($dateYear); ?></select>
                <a id="next" href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="javascript:swapContent('next')"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
            </h2>
            <div id="event_list" class="none"></div>
            <div id="calender_section_top">
                <ul>
                    <li>Mon</li>
                    <li>Tue</li>
                    <li>Wed</li>
                    <li>Thu</li>
                    <li>Fri</li>
                    <li>Sat</li>
                    <li>Sun</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="calender_section_bot">
                <ul>
                <?php
    $dayCount = 1;
    for ($cb = 1; $cb <= $boxDisplay; $cb++) {
        if (($cb >= $currentMonthFirstDay || $currentMonthFirstDay == 7) && $cb <= ($totalDaysOfMonthDisplay - 1)) {

            // Current date

            $currentDate = $dateYear . '-' . $dateMonth . '-' . $dayCount;
            $currentDate = strtotime($currentDate);
            $eventNum = 0;

            // Include db configuration file
            // Get number of events based on the current date

            $sql = ("SELECT COUNT(book2_id), date_from, date_to FROM booking_2 GROUP BY date_from ORDER BY COUNT(book2_id) DESC");
            $result = $this->connect()->query($sql);
            $eventNum = $result->num_rows;
            if ($eventNum > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                    $date_from = $row['date_from'];
                    $date_to = $row['date_to'];
                    $time_from = strtotime($date_from);
                    $time_fromm = idate('d', $time_from);
                    $time_to = strtotime($date_to);
                    $time_too = idate('d', $time_to);
                    if ($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to) {
                        echo '<li  style="background-color:#FF3232 !important;" date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
                    }
                    else {
                        echo '<li date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo '<li date="' . $currentDate . '" class="date_cell"><span>' . $dayCount . '</span>';
            }

            // Date cell

            echo '</li>';
            $dayCount++;
?>
                <?php
        }
        else { ?>
                    <li><span>&nbsp;</span></li>
                <?php
        }
    } ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: Your if .. "echo's" are AFTER the loop... so yes, only one echo. Probably you want them WITHIN the loop.

Beautify your code to see what you are doing.

Comment: What is Beautify?

Comment: The question is: what is Google? isn't that the first thing to do, or am I strange to think so?

Comment: What exactly do you not understand in this code? Are the else statements in the if expression confusing you? sorry if so.

Comment: I wrote: "Your if .. "echo's" are AFTER the loop... so yes, only one echo. Probably you want them WITHIN the loop. "  If you beautify your code, you will see that and think: OF COURSE! HOW COULD I NOT SEE THAT. And you will understand that it is not about my not understanding. Good luck. Just read closely what everyone here has written and you should get there.

Comment: It then creates a new problem, trust me I have tried. Here is the output I get when I incude the IF statements in the WHILE loop: https://prnt.sc/jq2ovq. It just duplicate all the dates basing on how many records there are. Please don't be mad.

Answer (score 1):

You end the while-loop before outputting the data. Try moving the ending bracket down past the section where you echo the info, like this:

```
$sql = ("SELECT * FROM booking_2 ORDER BY book2_id");
$result = $this->connect()->query($sql); 
$eventNum = $result->num_rows;
if($eventNum > 0){
  $previousDate = 0;
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $date_from = $row['date_from'];
    $date_to = $row['date_to'];
    $time_from = strtotime($date_from);
    $time_fromm = idate('d', $time_from);
    $time_to = strtotime($date_to);
    $time_too = idate('d', $time_to);

    if (date("Y-m-d", $time_from) != date("Y-m-d", $previousDate)) {
        if ($currentDate >= $time_from && $currentDate <= $time_to) {
           echo '<li id="'.$row['book2_id'].'" style="background-color:#FF3232 !important;" date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell"><span>'.$dayCount.'</span>';  
        }else{
           echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell"><span>'.$dayCount.'</span>';
        }
    }
    $previousDate = $time_from;
  }
}else{
    echo '<li date="'.$currentDate.'" class="date_cell"><span>'.$dayCount.'</span>';
}
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this, but when I do this the days just duplicate. For example if there are 2 records there are going to be two of the same dates. Here is a picture of how this looks if I include the if statement in the while loop: http://prntscr.com/jq2ovq

Comment: Right. I see what you mean. Fixing this requires an extra check, to see if the date has already been marked. Let me just update the answer to include that.

Comment: Oh, so simple, thank you! However I can't check this out now with my code. In the moring absolutely

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding but the solution you have provided still outputs the same bug. I thought that this would fix the bug when I looked at your edit. But now while testing it the solution still seems not fruitfull. Sorry for that :/

Comment: Well then, we're going to need more of your code to figure it out then. For instance, i'd like to know where exactly you get $currentDate and $dayCount, since those are never set in your code snippet. If they're made to only advance whenever actually used, then the sollution i sent won't work because it skips the part where they are used.

Comment: I have edited the question and have included more code. I am thinking maybe using arrays but as I am trying there is still no avail.

Comment: Is there any possible solution to this specific problem? I have to fix this problem as this is due very soon. I am very sorry to bother you :S.